# Feeding a population on sugar

Tags: humans, food

Population: 50000 humans

Average age: 46 years

Forced caloric intake: 2400-2900 kilocalories for males  and 1600-2000 kilocalories for females of which 80% coming from carbohydrates 5% from fat and 15% from protein

These humans will be forced to eat a mixture of whole foods that match the macro-biotic ratio and sugary water and  fruit juices

Will they all die from diabetes?

Comment: I think they don't even get 46 years old^^

Comment: The immediate problem with this diet will be fat deficiency, not excessive carbs.

Comment: There are fat soluble vitamins and essential fatty acids, but otherwise humans do not need calories from fat.

Comment: Well, America still has people living in it...

Comment: They would probably die of other vitamin defiecencies first for example vitamin B12 is bioavailabilite mostly from animal sources and from fortified plant products. Those of us who are unable to digest it from our diet need regular medication or we will suffer many symptoms such as anemia, loss of balance, nerve damage, dementia.

Comment: Ho much matters, if it is mostly  whole carbohydrates with only a tiny amount of sugar water there is no risk of diabetes or other health risk, other than hte complete lack of vitamins.

Comment: Humans normally  need around 2000 KILOcalories a day but for short we say only calories. For example a glass of milk has 840 calories=84 kilocalories.

Comment: @JBH - A dieter's "Calorie" is actually, technically, a kilocalorie.

Comment: @JBH you understood it wrong. [Read up on Kcal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No -- eating sugar does not cause diabetes.**

Confirming this are [Diabetes UK](https://www.diabetes.org.uk/guide-to-diabetes/enjoy-food/eating-with-diabetes/diabetes-food-myths/myth-sugar-causes-diabetes) and [American Diabetes Association](http://www.diabetes.org/diabetes-basics/myths/), among others. It is the intake of calories without sufficient expenditure of energy. If you are hyperactive, sugar can match your metabolic needs. If you are less active, sugar causes insulin spikes, leading to diabetes. But so can other foods. In other words, it ain’t the sugar, it’s the lack of sufficient activity.

Comment: This is one of the few places where I think splitting hairs between sugar and caloric imbalance is actually key to answering the question properly!  Fundamentally, insulin is managing blood sugar levels.  If your blood sugar levels are perfect for your lifestyle, then you're set!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific question that was asked, I would say there's certainly a distinct possibility of developing Type II diabetes (insulin resistance) due to constantly elevated blood sugar causing an eventual desensitization of the insulin receptor that controls a significant portion of the blood sugar response. Not sure how much biochemistry you really want here but I can go into detail if it would help.

According to Wikipedia, the "Western pattern diet" is about 50/15/35 carbs/protein/fat, so you're fine in terms of protein, but the extra carbs will certainly change the way energy usage and storage in the body will work.